# How to pass variable to html using jinja2 in EEL

Tags: python, html, jinja2, desktop-application, eel

For those who don't know EEL is python library that allows you to build desktop apps using web technologies. It's similar to Electron JS.
Is it possible to pass variable to jinja2 in html file from python? Or how can I achieve that?